# nfs client time out after apt upgrade updated nfs-common

Tags: mount, nfs

I am running virtual ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS node in a virtual cluster and have three nfs shares , shared between all instances. All the other nodes run on CentOS stream, but this one contains two GV100 GPUs and it always seemed easier to administer nvidia software in ubuntu hence the odd set-up.

Yesterday I ran the standard `apt update/upgrade` and among a few other tools `nfs-common` was updated to version 1.3.4-2.5ubuntu3.5. Since then I cannot connect to the NFS-shares anymore. Whenever I try I just get a mount.nfs timeout. I am pretty sure that this is a client-side problem since all the other (CentOS) nodes can still connect to the shares as usual.

I realized that the nfs-common service was masked after that so I unmasked and restarted it, but it didn't help, so I purged nfs common, restarted the instance, reinstalled it and tried again but the problem remains the same.

From what I read the most common mistake is a wrong IP for the nfs-server but I have not changed fstab since and only copy the path from there for the `mount -fav` trials, so I don't think this is the problem in my case. When I check `systemctl status nfs-common` every now and then I get this warning that I cannot quite make sense of

```
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: NFS support files common to client and server...
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu nfs-common[2464]:  * Starting NFS common utilities
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu rpc.statd[2488]: Version 1.3.3 starting
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu sm-notify[2489]: Version 1.3.3 starting
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu rpc.statd[2488]: Failed to read /var/lib/nfs/state: Success
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu rpc.statd[2488]: Initializing NSM state
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu nfs-common[2464]:    ...done.
Dec 05 15:24:52 gpu systemd[1]: Started LSB: NFS support files common to client and server.
```

But I am not sure if that is related. It also vanishes when I run systemctl restart `nfs-common`.

I do not have administrative access to the server running the nfs-shares but as mentioned I do not think its a server-side problem since all the other nodes are running fine. Is there any other service or config I need to make sure is set properly for the nfs client to work?

Please give me some advice, thank you in advance.

Edit: This is how my fstab entry looks

```
server:/path/share1  /mnt/work_data  nfs rw,vers=4.0  0 0
server:/path/share2  /mnt/raw_data   nfs rw,vers=4.0  0 0
server:/path/share3  /mnt/tools      nfs rw,vers=4.0  0 0
```